# TypeError: back() missing 1 required positional argument: 'image_number'

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make a working image viewer with tkinter using video. But for some reason, the back button just wouldn't work. Every time I tried to use the back button, I keep getting TypeError: back() missing 1 required positional argument: 'image_number'. I am new to python so it is probably an obvious mistake. Also you will have to use your own photos to test it.

Video link: https://www.youtube.com/watchv=zg4c92pNFeo&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV&index=9

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



root = Tk()
root.title("Image viewer")

my_img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/iu.gif"))
my_img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/player2.ico"))
my_img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/Codm.PNG"))
my_img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/Heroes online.png"))
my_img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/Google search.png"))

image_list = [my_img1, my_img2, my_img3, my_img4, my_img5]

my_label = Label(image=my_img1)
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

def forward(image_number):
    global my_label
    global button_forward
    global button_back

    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label= Label(image=image_list[image_number-1])
    button_forward= Button(root, text= ">>", command= lambda : forward(image_number+1))
    button_back= Button(root, text= "<<", command= lambda : back(image_number-1))

    if image_number == 5:
        button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", state= DISABLED)

    my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    button_quit.grid(row=1, column=1)
    button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

def back(image_number):
    global my_label
    global button_forward
    global button_back

    my_label.grid_forget()
    my_label = Label(image=image_list[image_number-1])
    button_forward = Button(root, text=">>", command=lambda: forward(image_number+1))
    button_back = Button(root, text="<<", command=lambda: back(image_number-1))

    my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    button_quit.grid(row=1, column=1)
    button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)



button_back = Button(root, text= "<<", command= back)
button_quit = Button(root, text= "Exit program", command=root.quit)
button_forward = Button(root, text = ">>", command= lambda : forward(2))

button_back.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_quit.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

This is the error I keep getting

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: back() missing 1 required positional argument: 'image_number'
```

Comment: The error is telling you precisely what is wrong. `back` requires an argument. You aren't passing an argument.

Comment: For your design, you should not set the `command` option when creating the back button.  Also you should not create new buttons (both back and forward) whenever the back or forward button is clicked, just update the `command` option of the two buttons is enough.

Comment: I don't have any idea of what argument is supposed to pass through it. In the video, there was no argument for back and it worked fine for him. I asked about it but his response wasn't really helpful

Comment: The linkyou included is not working + `button_back = Button(root, text= "<<", command= back)` there is no supplied argument here, maybe you missed something that he did somewhere, take a close look

Comment: @CoolCloud  I think this link should work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg4c92pNFeo&t=1198s

Comment: Check the answer below for getting some idea

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you could do to clean up this code:

- Create the image list without individual variables
- Don't recreate the label and buttons for each photo
- Use a global image index to indicate the current image
- Use the buttons to change the index, and call the same function to update the label and button states.

Try this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Image viewer")

image_list = [  # all images
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/iu.gif")),
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/player2.ico")),
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/Codm.PNG")),
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/Heroes online.png")),
ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images/Google search.png"))
]

image_number = 0  # current image

my_label = Label(image=image_list[image_number])  # holds photo
my_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

def forward():  # forward button
    global image_number
    image_number+=1 # next photo
    updatelabel()
    
def back():  # back button
    global image_number
    image_number-=1  # previous photo
    updatelabel()
    
def updatelabel():  # show current photo
    my_label.configure(image=image_list[image_number]) # show image
    my_label.image = image_list[image_number]  # prevent garbage collection
    button_forward["state"] = "normal"    
    button_back["state"] = "normal"    
    if image_number == len(image_list)-1: # if last image
       button_forward["state"] = "disabled"
    if image_number == 0:    # if first image
       button_back["state"] = "disabled"


button_back = Button(root, text= "<<", command= back)
button_back["state"] = "disabled"  # start at first photo
button_quit = Button(root, text= "Exit program", command=root.quit)
button_forward = Button(root, text = ">>", command= lambda : forward())

button_back.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_quit.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_forward.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code will raise exception when back button is clicked more than 5 times after program starts.  So better disable back button at first.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! This program is much better than the one in the tutorial video. Though I still don't understand why I got the error in the initial program while in the video they did not.

Comment: You're original button called `back` with no parameters: `button_back = Button(root, text= "<<", command= back)`. It should be `....back(1))`.